# confused newbie: js form validate inline

Tags: javascript, html

I built a form that I need to validate with JavaScript. I tried to use this post but cannot duplicate the results: [inline javascript form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841119/inline-javascript-form-validation)

I've created a JSBin with my code so far, including CSS and JS files: http://jsbin.com/oligol/1/edit

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>xxx</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
  <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />

  <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />

 <meta name="description" content="" />

 <meta name="keywords" content="" />   

 <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master.css";</style>  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "css/master.css";</style>
<script src="contact.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="page-container">     

<div id="header"> <img src="images/header.jpg" width="900" height="243" />
</div>

  <div id="main-nav"> 
    <ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="index.html" >HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="req.html">REQUIREMENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="Links.html">LINKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="feedback.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" id="current">CONTACT US</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>

<div id="content"> 
 <p><p><p>xxxxxxx welcomes all correspondence.<br /> 
   Please use the form below for any questions, feedback and suggestions.<br />
   or call &nbsp; <strong><em>xxx xxx </em> &nbsp;&nbsp;xxx.xxx.7009 </strong><br />
   All information is confidential<br />
 <!--  <b>* required fields</b>-->

<form onSubmit="return checkForm(); method="post" action="xxx@gmail.com" >
 <fieldset><strong>* required fields</strong>
 <legend>Contact Form</legend>

 <label for="name"> Name :  <span class="required"></span></label>

 <div class="input">
   <input type="text" name="txtName" id="name" size="30" /><span class="message"></span>
 </div>

 <div class="error" id="emailError"> 
      Required: Please enter your email address 
    </div> 
    <div class="error" id="emailError2"> 
      This doesn't look like a real email address, please check and reenter 
    </div> 
      <label for="FieldData2"><strong> E-mail 
 address * :</strong> 
 </label>

 <div class="input">
 <input type="text" name="FieldData1" id="FieldData2" value="" size="30" /><span class="message"></span>
 </div> 

 <label for="comments"> <strong>Message * :</strong>
 </label><span class="message"></span>

 <div class="input">

 <textarea name="Message" id="message" margin-left="20px"
 margin-bottom="20px" rows="18" cols="40">
 </textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" >

 </div>

 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </div> 

 <div id="footer"> 

    <p>Copyrights 2013 xxx xxx &nbsp;|&nbsp; Web Design by xxx</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url(../images/backgrd.jpg);   
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#page-container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

#containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; } 
.cornerimage { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; } 


#main-nav {
    margin-top: -142px;
    height: 40px;
}

#navlist {
    margin-left: 290px;
    padding:0;
    text-align: left;
}

#navlist ul, #navlist li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 16px;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist a:link, #navlist a:visited {
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CDCDCD;
}

#navlist a:link#current, #navlist a:visited#current,
#navlist a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    background: clear;
    color: #000000;
}


#header {
    height: 243px;
    background: #CDCDCD;
    }

#sidebar-a {
    float: right;
    width: 181px;
    height: 441px;
}

#ftcredits {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    font-family:Tahome, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #5d3b28;
}

#ftcredits a:link, a:visited {
    color: #666633;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#ftcredits a:hover {
    color: #db6d16;
}

#content {
    padding-left: 70px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    background: #CDCDCD;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#footer { 
    font-family:Tahome, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
    background: #CDCDCD;
    padding: 1px 20px;
    line-height: 13px;
    border-top: 2px solid #5d3b28;
}

#footer a {
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}

#footer a:hover {
    color: #003366;
}

h1 {color: #801F18;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}


h2 {
    color: #801F18;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #663333;
    line-height:150%
}

exc {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000000;
    line-height:150%
}

p {
    line-height:150%
}

h3 {
    color: #666633;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
height: 350px;
margin-top: -350px;
margin-left: 460px;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 13px;
}
.double_column_list li {float:left; width:50%;
}

fieldset{ padding:10px;
          width:600px;
}
label {width:170px;
       float:left;
       text-align:right;
       clear:both;
       margin-bottom:20px;
    }

.input {width:350px;
      float:left;
      margin-left:10px;
      }

error{
    }

#content a {
    color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

#content h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#content p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:150%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.container1 {
    display: inline;
  float: left;
    width: 320px;
    height:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 1px solid #black;
    zoom: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(83,85,89,0.3);
}

.container2 {
    width: 320px;
    height:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline;
  float: left;
    /*-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: 1px solid #black;
    zoom: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(83,85,89,0.3);*/

}
```

This is my JS:

```
  function checkForm() {
  hideAllErrors();
  var formIsValid =
    /*showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData0', isEmpty, 'nameError')*/
    /*&&*/ showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData2', isEmpty, 'emailError');
    showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData2', isAnInvalidEmail, 'emailError2');
    /*&& showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData3', isEmpty, 'categoryError')*/
     showErrorAndFocusIf('FieldData1', isEmpty, 'messageError');

  /* For debugging, lets prevent the form from submitting. */
  if (formIsValid) {
    alert("Valid form!");
    return false;
  }

  return formIsValid;
}

function showErrorAndFocusIf(fieldId, predicate, errorId) {
  var field = document.getElementById(fieldId);
  if (predicate(field)) {
    document.getElementById(errorId).style.display = 'inline';
    if (field.select) {
      field.select();
    }
    field.focus();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function isEmpty(field) {
  return field.value == '';
}

function isAnInvalidEmail(field) {
  var email = field.value;

  var ok = "1234567890qwertyuiop[]asdfghjklzxcvbnm.@-_QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";

  for(i = 0; i < email.length; i++){
    if(ok.indexOf(email.charAt(i)) < 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  re = /(@.*@)|(\.\.)|(^\.)|(^@)|(@$)|(\.$)|(@\.)/;
  re_two = /^.+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
  return re.test(email) || !re_two.test(email);
}



function hideAllErrors() {
  /*document.getElementById("nameError").style.display = "none"*/
  document.getElementById("emailError").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("emailError2").style.display = "none";
  /*document.getElementById("categoryError").style.display = "none"*/
  document.getElementById("messageError").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

Your HTML is invalid, you should something like the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to check your HTML.

You element names and ids are inconsistent. E.g. Your "Name" field is named "txtName" but has the id "name" and your "E-mail address" field is named "FieldData**1**" but has the id "FieldData**2**". Use consistent and sensible names so that the HTML and JavaScript are easy to write and understand.

You've broken the JavaScript by removing the AND operators (&&) in the `checkForm` function. The `showErrorAndFocusIf` function returns a boolean value that is true when the specified field is valid. The return values of the calls are supposed to be combined for all of the validation constraints to determine if the whole form has passed validation.

Lastly, the ids of the fields and error messages used in the JavaScript did not match the HTML. The JavaScript uses the DOM's `getElementById` function to retrieve references to the fields and the error messages in the HTML, so you have to make sure that the ids match in order for the code to work.

I've corrected these problems in a new JSBin: http://jsbin.com/otinoz/2/edit

Comment: three things going on now.. one i will try to use what you teach me to apply to then "comments" field..2), you are a genius..3) i wanna have your baby..also, thanx you verrry much